# Javascript error when I try to add click event to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var spanclickhandler = $('.officeapprovalspan').click(function () {
    // do some stuff
});
```

Basically, I have this `spanclickhandler`. Anything with the class `officeapprovalspan` on loading the page gets this assigned to its click event. No problems there.

In another place I have the code:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<span class="officeapprovalspan">wero<span>');
$(document).on('click', '.officeapprovalspan', spanclickhandler);
```

So I'm replacing some HTML with a new span of this class. I use the on to add the click event to the spans of class `officeapprovalspan`. I gather I have to do this because the new span will not have the click handler attached to it.

So that's OK, but when I click the new span I get this error:

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

Comment: `.click()` returns the jQuery object it was called on, not a function. Then you are trying to use this jQuery object as an event handler. It's like you called `$(document).on('click', '.officeapprovalspan', $('.officeapprovalspan'));` which does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: I would look at using a loop function for this. `for (var i = 0, len = var.length; i < len; i = i + 1)` and use a type of event utility. This most likely will not work with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The `click` method doesn't return the event handler, it returns the jQuery object. Define the event handler first, and use it in the click method:

```
var spanclickhandler = function () {
    ...

    do some stuff

    ...
};

$('.officeapprovalspan').click(spanclickhandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

This chunk of code doesn't do what you think it does (I'm pretty sure that handler function isn't returned):

```
var spanclickhandler = $('.officeapprovalspan').click(function () {
    ...

    do some stuff

    ...
});
```

I suggest you code it like this, which should work:

```
var spanclickhandler = function () {
    ...

    do some stuff

    ...
}

$('.officeapprovalspan').click(spanclickhandler);
```

Comment: Yes, you gessed right, the `click` method doesn't return the function, it returns the jQuery object that it's used on.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

```
var spanclickhandler = function () {
        ...

        do some stuff

        ...
};

$(this).replaceWith('<span class="officeapprovalspan">wero<span>');
$('.officeapprovalspan').on('click', spanclickhandler);
```

**OR BETTER**

```
$(document).on('click', '.officeapprovalspan' function () {
        ...

        do some stuff

        ...
});
// Because 'on' will attach event on DOM element even if they are not created yet, if you define a selector descendant inside. You can replace `document` by the nearest top parent of all your `.officeapprovalspan` and it will improve performance. `document` is not really optimal here
$(this).replaceWith('<span class="officeapprovalspan">wero<span>');
```

Comment: No, as you use it, the `on` method will *not* attach events on elements that doesn't exist yet. For that to work you have to use the delegate syntax, and attach it to a parent element that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

`spanclickhandler` returns a jQuery object, `$('.officeapprovalspan')` in this case. You need to either create a separate function or use event namescapes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<span class="officeapprovalspan">wero<span>').click(spanclickhandler);
```